# Correct way of calling await inside SignalR 2.0 OnReceived handler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, signalr, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm using SignalR 2.0.1 with `PersistentConnection` (not hubs) and currently my default very simple OnReceived handler looks like this:

```
protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
    return Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```

I want to add some I/O-bound code to this handler, like accessing a DB on a different machine. Naturally I want everything to be asynchronous and I don't want to block the thread so I'm hoping to use an async flavor like `db.SaveChangesAsync()` of EF6 (instead of the regular blocking `db.SaveChanges`).

I added the `db.SaveChangesAsync()` to the handler, but I need to `await` on it too. So I've also added an `async` modifier to the handler, but this caused an error with my return value - I can't return `Connection.Broadcast(data)` anymore.

This is what I got eventually:

```
protected override async Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
    // some EF code here..

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    // the original return changes into this?
    await Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this? Because I have a feeling I'm abusing the pattern.

---

btw, if I understand correctly, the current version of SignalR is fully asynchronous. Older versions like the one described [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) had two handlers - one synchronous and one asynchronous (with the `Async` postfix).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a perfectly reasonable way of going about it. Why do you feel that you may be abusing the pattern?

Think of it this way:

- a synchronous method returning `void` corresponds to an async method returning `Task`. Likewise,
- a synchronous method returning `T` corresponds to an async method returning `Task<T>`.

That is why you cannot do

```
protected override async Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
    return Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```

, since the `async` keyword and your return statement would indicate a method that returned `Task<Task>`.

What you can do is remove your last `await` altogether. All it will do is create an empty continuation (because it is essentially saying "when the broadcast is done, run the code after the broadcast and until the ending curly brace"). Or you can leave it in for consistency, if you prefer.

Comment: My confusion is this: Before I added the async modifier, was the OnReceive function asynchronous? Because the code here suggests it was: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx

Comment: Removing the last `await` changes the behavior if `Broadcast` throws an exception.

Comment: @talkol It depends a bit on what you mean by async - async in relation to what? When you send a message, internally the task of delivering the message is handed over to a thread from  the thread pool, so in that sense you could say that it is async whether your mark the OnReceived method async or not.

Answer (score 3):

I have an [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) on my blog that you may find helpful.

A `Task` instance represents a "future". So when you're doing this:

```
protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
  return Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```

You're saying "`OnReceived` is done when `Connection.Broadcast(data)` is done". This is practically the same as:

```
protected override async Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
  await Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```

Which is saying "`OnReceived` will (asynchronously) wait for `Connection.Broadcast(data)` to be done, and then `OnReceived` will be done." It's slightly more efficient *without* the `async` and `await`, but they have practically the same semantics.

So, yes, this code would be correct:

```
protected override async Task OnReceived(IRequest request, string connectionId, string data)
{
  // some EF code here..
  await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  await Connection.Broadcast(data);
}
```